# I cannot connect to my SQL Server 2012 Express over ip 127.0.0.1, local and localhost

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I cannot connect to my SQL Server 2012 Express instance using addresses `127.0.0.1`, `local` and `localhost`.

I added ports and test the databases on ODBC. I can also login over SQL Server management with all users but when I am trying to login over IP I get this error:

> Login failed for user 'ipinfo'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ipinfo'. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

I have no connection strings but 'all i know is i am using mixed mode and all my users have the priviliges and access to the all databases.' i can 'login' with the same 'username' and 'passwd' using each 'users' and 'passwd' through the é Microsoft SQL Server Management 2012 Express ' but the real problem is when i lunch my 'Charserver.exe'

> 'which is a game server exe i use in my game servers, it is failing to connect to the required  DBs. '
>
> All ports and remote connection settings are done.
>
> ' My game server and the DBs are all on the same machine. '

Comment: Please show the code you used to try to open the database.

Comment: Is it primary instance? If not, you need append your instance name after `localhost`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders
**i'm trying to connect my DB with my exe. it's a game server "charserver.exe" and here is the config strings .exe file is reading:**

`<add key="characterCS" value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=character;User ID=character;Password=tai;" /> <add key="itemlogCS" value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=itemlog;User ID=loger;Password=tai;" /> <add key="ipinfoCS" value="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=ipinfo;User ID=ipinfo;Password=tai;" />`

Comment: That's not the code you used to open the database. Please include the connection strings, _and the code_ in your question. You can edit your question. Click the "edit" link. I hope you realize that you need _code_ to open the database. The connection strings are not enough by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Open SQL server configuration manager and under your SQL Server Network Configuration for each protocol you find enable the TCP/IP Protocol and restart your services. It should work.